# Apply CSS3 transitions to some media queries, but not all

Tags: css, media-queries, css-transitions

I am changing the width of a DIV with the following CSS:

```
div { width:100px; }

@media only screen and (min-width: 400px) {
    div { width:300px; }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    div { width:500px; }
}
```

Is it possible to use CSS transitions to animate the change in width from 300 to 500 and from 500 to 300, without animating the change from 100 to 300 and from 300 to 100?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fireman_biff/T7A5v/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>You can just put the transition on last media query http://jsfiddle.net/T7A5v/1/</strike>

**EDIT:** I see what you mean, you can give this a try instead: http://jsfiddle.net/T7A5v/2/ The trick is to transition a `min-width` instead of the `width` itself.

```
div {
    background: red;
    width: 100px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 400px) {
    div {
        width: 300px;
        min-width: 300px;
        -webkit-transition: min-width 3s;
        -moz-transition: min-width 3s;
        -o-transition: min-width 3s;
        transition: min-width 3s;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    div {
        min-width: 500px;
        -webkit-transition: min-width 3s;
        -moz-transition: min-width 3s;
        -o-transition: min-width 3s;
        transition: min-width 3s;
    }
}
```

Comment: This only animates the change from 300 to 500, not the change from 500 to 300. I'll reword my question to make it clearer that I need both cases animated.